# Generate a new variable from row conditions in Stata

Tags: stata

I am using Stata13 on Windows 7. I have a dataset with repeated observations of `age` and `educ` in a row for each `id`. i.e. variables `q9p1educ` and `q9p1age` is the education and age for person1 respectively , `q9p2educ` and `q9p2age` is the education and age for person2 respectively etc. I want to extract the education level of the person with the highest age. I have managed to extract the maximum age `maxage` using `egen maxage = rowmax(q9p1age - q9p9age)` How can I get the education of the person with the maximum age? 
The sample data is [here](https://github.com/Keniajin/rr/blob/master/dat/sample_data.csv)

Comment: Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see criteria for a good question, including attempt at code and self-contained reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by reshaping your data into long format

```
reshape long q9@educ q9@age, i(id maxage) j(pid) string
```

Then the answer depends on What do you want to do if the maxage is not unique. Perhaps you could do something like average them?

```
bysort id (age): gen temp=q9educ if age==maxage
bysort id: egen educmaxage=mean(temp)
drop temp
```

Then if you want it wide again, you could simply reshape wide.

```
reshape wide q9@educ q9@age, i(id maxage educmaxage) j(pid) string
```

Comment: this code also helped after a thought 
`foreach var of varlist q9p1age- q9p9age  {
if maxage==`var' {
 local x=substr("`var'",1,4) 
 local edu= "`x'edu"
 replace maxEduc=`edu'  
 
 } 
}`